# Python formatting new lines

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I want to change python linter to put only 1 new empty line not 3 as here. (VS CODE with auto formatting on save) 
I already searched in Python Extension settings but unlucky ...

Can someone help ? Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Have the same problem as of 2019, did you solve it?